# Risks associated with allowing users to generate functions from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a feature on my website where users can run some code they write against some test cases (similar to leetcode). However, I am concerned by allowing such a feature I am allowing malicious users to write code that will break the site. Is there any workaround to this, and is it even something worth stressing over?

For context:

- This is a very small feature and not at all the primary function of the website.
- The website has no backend of sorts (no token storage, or user specific data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data doesn't get transferred to other users, or even from a user to the site, it should be fine. Nothing to worry about, since any "malicious" code someone writes will only affect *their* machine - and if you perform common-sense checks and they happen to break some functionality of your site anyway, that's on them, not on the site.

Anyone on the internet can already go to any site and open up the console and type in and run whatever code they want, but that in itself isn't an issue for the site to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I guess what I needed was some peace of mind